# HTaccess 404 with mod_rewrite

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

I've got a small problem with my HTaccess urls. I wanted to make my URLs more SEO friendly, my current URL is:

> url.com/blogitem/2

url.com -> Domain ; blog -> blogitem.php ; 2 -> ID for the blog item to get from the DB

Now I would like the URL to be like this:

> url.com/blogitem/2/name-title-info

I've made the HTaccess part and the PHP part for it, but it will give me a 404 error page in return every time I visited the URL.

The HTaccess part:

```
# Blog SEO Urls.
RewriteRule ^blog/([0-9]*)/?$        blog.php?page=$1    [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^blogitem/([0-9]*)/?$/([a-z]*)/?$    blogitem.php?id=$1&name=$2    [NC,L]
```

The PHP part:

```
$trancTitle = trim(strtolower($blogTitle));
$underscoreTitle = preg_replace('/\s+/', '-', $trancTitle);
<a href="blogitem/<?php echo $blogId; ?>/<?php echo $underscoreTitle;?>">
```

Can someone explain why I'm getting an error page in return(404 to be exactly). I'm sorry for my bad English, it isn't my mother tongue. Thanks for helping in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex doesn't seem right, try these 2 rules:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Blog SEO Urls.
RewriteRule ^blog/([0-9]+)/?$ blog.php?page=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^blogitem/([0-9]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ blogitem.php?id=$1&name=$2 [QSA,NC,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

The url that you are showing does not have "/" at the end: url.com/blogitem/2/name-title-info
Then you have mentioned blog.php in your .htaccess I think you are wanting to have this url too url.com/blog/2

So, you need to change a little bit you regular expression, try to putting this in your .htaccess:

```
# Blog SEO Urls.
RewriteRule ^blog/([0-9]+)$ blog.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^blogitem/([0-9]+)/([a-z]+)$ /blogitem.php?id=$1&name=$2 [L]
```

Then in your php you will receive the variables via GET method
Try this to see that:

```
<?php
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($_GET);
    echo '</pre>';
?>
```